# Upgrading to angularfire 2 and firebase 3 error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, upgrade, angularfire

Upgrading to angularfire.js 2 and firebase.js 3, I'm getting the following errors:

```
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getProjectConfig?key= .........
404 (Not Found)
- XMLHttpRequest cannot load ......... Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it on a local server. You are getting the CORS-error.

if you look at the firebase you will see two whitelisted url. One is localhost and the other is your-firebase-project-name.firebase.google.com